# Finding the value of this Riemann sum

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-sum

I am asked to find the value of:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum^n_{i=1}f\left(\frac{(\sum^i_{k=0}\alpha_k)^2}{(\sum^n_{k=0}\alpha_k)^2}\right)\frac{\alpha_i}{\sum^n_{k=0} \alpha_k}$$

Where $(\alpha_i)$ is a sequence of real numbers such that $\forall i \in \mathbb{N}\;\;\; 0 < \alpha_i < 1$, $\sum^\infty_{i=0}\alpha_i$ is a divergent sum, and $f$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$.

Usually, the way I would do this is to fiddle around with it until I get it into this form:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{b-a}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n f\left (a + \frac{i}{n} (b-a) \right)$$

Then the answer is just $\int^b_a f(x) dx$. But I don't see any way to do this. Is there some algebraic trick I'm missing to get this into the right form?

Comment: The $n$th sum is a Riemann sum of the function $x\mapsto f(x^2)$ on $[0,1]$ for the partition $P_n=(x_i)_{1\leqslant i\leqslant  n}$ defined by $x_i=A_i/A_n$ where $A_i=\sum\limits_{k=0}^i\alpha_k$ for every $i\geqslant1$. Then the fact that the mesh of $P_n$ goes to zero (to be checked) and that $f$ is Riemann integrable proves that this converges to $\int_0^1f(x^2)dx$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With fixed $n$, let $x_0=0$ and $x_i=\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^i\alpha_k}{\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha_k}$, $1\le i\le n$. Then $\{x_0,\dots,x_n\}$ is a partition of $[0,1]$.

Moreover
$$
x_i-x_{i-1}=\frac{\alpha_i}{\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha_k}<\frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha_k},\quad 1\le i\le n.
$$
Since $\sum\alpha_k$ is divergent,
$$
\sup_{i\le i\le n}(x_i-x_{i-1})\to0\text{ as }n\to\infty.
$$
The sum can be rewritten as
$$
\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i^2)(x_i-x_{i-1}),
$$
which is a Riemann sum for $\int_0^1f(x^2)\,dx$.